# Mean squared error and its root

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

This probably is a very stupid question. Nonetheless, I am a bit unsure.

Let $\mathscr{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $\mathscr{M}$ a closed subspace. Moreover, let $x\in\mathscr{H}$.

Is then
$$
\lVert x-\hat{x}\rVert=\inf_{y\in\mathscr{M}}\lVert x-y\rVert~~\Leftrightarrow~~\lVert x-\hat{x}\rVert^2=\inf_{y\in\mathscr{M}}\lVert x-y\rVert^2?
$$

($\hat{x}$ exists uniquely by the orthogonal projection theorem. So my question is whether this theorem gives the element $\hat{x}$ which minimizes the mean squared error $\lVert x-y\rVert^2$.)

Comment: $x^{2}$ and $\sqrt{x}$ are monotone, which means they preserve $\inf$.

Comment: okay, so the equivalence holds. cool, thank you